# 'UIView' may not respond to 'addSubview:withAnimation:'

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I got this warning:

```
'UIView' may not respond to 'addSubview:withAnimation:'
```

The line of code which produce that warning is this:

```
[self.masterView addSubview:self.detailImage withAnimation:def];
```

And my relevant code is like this:

```
ExUIViewAnimationDefinition *def = [[ExUIViewAnimationDefinition alloc] init];
    def.type = ExUIAnimationTypeTransition;
    def.direction = ExUIAnimationDirectionMoveUp;
    [self.masterView addSubview:self.detailImage withAnimation:def];
    [def release];
```

I looked on the `UIView` documentation, i thought addSubview may be deprecated, but it still like this.

Does any one know how to solve this warning? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addSubview` is a method UIView will respond to. `addSubview:withAnimation:` is not a method UIView will respond to.

If you want to add a subview with a fade or something like that, try this:

```
self.detailImage.alpha = 0.0;
[self.masterView addSubview:self.detailImage];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.detailImage.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply, i have a question, why you choosed the values `0.3` and `1.0`? I have edited my post so you can take a look on the relevant code, may be you would update your answer for more accurate code. Any way, thanx for your help :))

Comment: 0.3 is the time (in seconds, so 0.3 seconds) the animation takes to complete, 1.0 means the alpha is 1, or 0 transparency.

Comment: You're still using `addSubview:withAnimation`, a method UIView doesn't respond to.

Answer (score 1):

To add a subview to a parent, call the addSubview: method of the parent view. This method adds the subview to the end of the parent’s list of subviews.
To insert a subview in the middle of the parent’s list of subviews, call any of the insertSubview:... methods of the parent view. Inserting a subview in the middle of the list visually places that view behind any views that come later in the list.

```
[self.masterView addSubView:self.def];
[def release];
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to animate subview by sliding out from down of border of parent view

```
    -(void) addAnimatadView:(UIView *) animatedView toView:(UIView *)aView {
        CGRect frame = animatedView.frame;
        float origin = frame.origin.y;
        frame.origin.y = aView.frame.size.height;
        [animatedView setFrame:frame];
        [aView addSubview:animatedView];
        frame.origin.y = origin;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{[animatedView setFrame:frame];}];
    }
```

Just change frame origins as you want to reach free sliding